# How to Calculate the Percentage In MVC

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller

I have two table in database named ProjectList and TaskList.The TaskList table columns are task name,description,startdate,enddate,Status,Project. The Project column Stores the Project name.Each Project having No.of Tasks.And I have a two view called ProjectDetails,TaskDetails. I am getting ProjectDetails page Dynamicly based on the project name it will redirect to TaskDetails page.Now I need to calculate the Project Percentage for each task Based on Tasks(Total No of Completed Task /Total  Task).

How Can I Achieve this one Please Help me.

Code for ProjectDetails page is bellow

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   @if (item.ProjectStatus == "OnGoing")
    {
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 cur-pointer">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectName)</h5>
        <div class="card-options">
        <a asp-action="EditProject" asp-route-id="@item.ProjectID">
        <i class="fa fa-edit icon-size icon-align"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="card-options-collapse" data-toggle="card-collapse"></a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <a asp-action="AllTask" asp-route-id="@item.ProjectName" style="color:#000 !important">
        <div class="card-body cur-pointer">
        <p class="tag tag-blue mb-3">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectStatus)</p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectDescription)</p>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>Scope:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectScope)</div>
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>Family:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectFamily)</div>
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>Bucket:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProjectBucket)</div>
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>Manager:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manager)</div>
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>Start Date:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)</div>
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>End Date:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)</div>
        <div class="col-5 py-1"><strong>Cost:</strong></div>
        <div class="col-7 py-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Budget)</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float-left"><strong>**TaskPErcentage**%</strong></div>
        <div class="float-right"><small class="text-muted">Progress</small>'
        </div>

        </a>
        </div>
        </div>
    }
 }
```

And My Controller is:

```
 public IActionResult AllProject()
    {
        List<Project> lstProject = new List<Project>();
        lstProject = objproject.GetAllProject().ToList();
        return View(lstProject);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In TaskDetails page : May be you are getting all task related to respective ProjectName comming from ProjectDetails.
So just do like inside your foreach on the base of task status:

```
before foreach : $completed = $totalTask = 0;


$totalTask++;

@if(item.ProjectStatus == "completed")
{
     $completed++;
}

$percentage  = ((int)$completed / (int) $totalTask ) * 100
```

Comment: Here Each Table having Column Status,The projectList contain ProjectStatus and TaskList contain TaskStatus...I want to get thte Task Status in ProjectDetails page

Comment: As you have been mentioned "The Project column Stores the Project name.Each Project having No.of Tasks". This means you can easily get all the on the base of task id or task name using Eloquent or joining those table. After that you can use that percentage calculation.

Comment: if you are storing id of table1 in table2(Task table)  then you can use one-many relation to get all task